# Product of two random variables should belong to additively closed family of distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables in $\mathcal{D_1}$ and $\mathcal{D_2}$ respectively(two families of distributions).

Can you suggest some pairs of $\mathcal{D_1}$ and $\mathcal{D_2}$ such that the product $XY$ belongs to a family $\mathcal{D_0}$ which is additively closed?

By additively closed I mean given $a\in \mathcal{D_0}$ and $b\in \mathcal{D_0}$, $(a+b)\in \mathcal{D_0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand the question properly, Normal distributions are additively closed so if we take $D_0=N$ and $D_1=N$ and $D_2=IG$ (inverse gamma) then $D_1 *D_2 \in D_0$ which is additively closed.

Comment: Why is the product of a Normal and an Inverse Gamma a Normal?

Comment: That just came to mind from Bayesian linear regression...https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture5.pdf